# Generate Rules with loop in Scikit Fuzzy

Tags: python

I'm trying to transform the expression:

```py
txt1 = atribute[0] & atribute[1] & atribute[2] & atribute[3]
```

(atribute is a list of strings)

in a loop for atribute with N dimension.

I've tried the following code

```py
for i in range(N)
    txt2.append(str(atributo[i]) + "&")
```

but txt1 is of type `skfuzzy.control.term.TermAggregate` and `txt2` is only a list. So i can't generate the rules.

Comment: Can you please update your question with a minimal, reproducible example? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) to reduce a sequence of objects to a single object.

```py
import functools

functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, attribute)
```

This is equivalent to running

```py
attribute[0] & attribute[1] ... & attribute[N]
```

Comment: Thanks man! But it worked partially, because the type is a string, not skfuzzy.control.term.TermAggregate. So I can't generate rules still.